# Backend API fetch works on npm start (json) but converts to html when using npm build on netlify

Tags: python, json, reactjs, flask, netlify

So I have a flask backend server using sqlalchemy and this is working perfectly fine, all I am using it for is a very simple API that you can add information to from react so flask backend and react front end. What I am trying to do is get the JSON from my /info route (already has proxy) and display it on the screen. Everything had been going really smooth until I went to run npm build on netlify. This returns the error `Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0 when building` and I have looked around and found out that I am receiving this error because if I check my network in my dev tools I can see that the get request comes back as HTML rather than JSON. I have tried trouble shooting this with netlifys `_headers` config but to no avail. The weirdest part is that on my localhost if I run npm start or npm dev the get request will return the intended JSON, I have looked around and I couldn't find anything else related to this issue besides some stuff on serviceWorkers which didn't help me. One thing I might add although I'm not sure it has any significance, I am hosting the Flask webserver on Heroku and I have a proxy in my `package.json` that routes to it.

DataTable.js (only file that deals with API in full project)

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

const DataTable = ({ refresh, setRefresh }) => {
  const [name, setName] = useState("");
  const [age, setAge] = useState("");
  const [language, setLanguage] = useState("");
  const [infos, setInfo] = useState([]);
  const handlePost = async () => {
    setRefresh(refresh + 1);
    const info = { name, age, language };
    const response = await fetch("/add_info", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        Accept: "application/json",
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(info),
    });

    if (response.ok) {
      onNewInfo(info);
      setName("");
      setAge(0);
      setLanguage("");
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("/info").then((response) =>
      response.json().then((data) => {
        setInfo(data.info);
      })
    );
  }, []);

  const onNewInfo = (info) => setInfo((currentInfo) => [info, ...currentInfo]);

  return (
    <div>
      <form>
        <div className="form__group field">
          <input
            required
            type="input"
            className="form__field"
            placeholder="Name"
            name="name"
            id="name"
            value={name}
            onChange={(e) => setName(e.target.value)}
          />
          <label for="name" className="form__label">
            Name
          </label>
        </div>
        <div className="form__group field">
          <input
            required
            type="number"
            className="form__field"
            placeholder="Name"
            name="name"
            id="name"
            value={age}
            onChange={(e) => setAge(e.target.value)}
          />
          <label for="name" className="form__label">
            Age
          </label>
        </div>
        <div className="form__group field">
          <input
            required
            type="input"
            className="form__field"
            placeholder="Message"
            name="message"
            id="message"
            value={language}
            onChange={(e) => setLanguage(e.target.value)}
          />
          <label for="message" className="form__label">
            Favorite Language
          </label>
          <button onClick={handlePost}>Submit</button>
        </div>
      </form>
      <table>
        <tr>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Age</th>
          <th>Favorite Language</th>
        </tr>
        {infos.map((info) => {
          return (
            <tr>
              <td>{info.name}</td>
              <td>{info.age}</td>
              <td>{info.language}</td>
            </tr>
          );
        })}
      </table>
    </div>
  );
};

export default DataTable;
```

app.py (not sure if this is needed but will provide regardless)

```py
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
import json

app = Flask(__name__)
db = SQLAlchemy()
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///database.db'
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

class Info(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(50))
    age = db.Column(db.Integer)
    language = db.Column(db.String(50))

@app.route('/add_info', methods=['POST'])
def add_info():
    info_data = request.get_json()

    new_info = Info(name=info_data['name'], age=info_data['age'], language=info_data['language'])

    db.session.add(new_info)
    db.session.commit()

    return 'Done', 201

@app.route('/info')
def info():
    info_list = Info.query.all()
    infos = []

    for info in info_list: 
        infos.append({'name': info.name, 'age' : info.age, 'language' : info.language})

    return jsonify({'info': infos}) 


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

If any additional information is needed I will be happy to provide it. Any help would be greatly appreciated thank you!

Comment: have you tried testing the flask server with postman?

Comment: @TenaciousB Yes I have, I have made get and post requests and it works as intended. The localhost with the React front end also works perfectly fine it's just when I build it on netlify I get the problem.